# Google maps - load polygon on marker click

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I have a kml file with polygon data that is too complex to load onto one googlemap as it contains thousands of latlng coordinates that just wont load all at once.

My question is, is it possible to load just one polygon when a map marker is clicked? I have a mysql database table that holds the latlngs for each marker and the table also has a column for polyCoords. I am looping through the data using php which displays all the markers correctly. Can i then add a listener to the markers which will load the data from the polyCoords column and just show the polygon for that clicked map marker?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize()
{

    var centre = new google.maps.LatLng(34.233753,-83.828712);

    var myOptions =
    {
        zoom: 4,
        center: centre,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    <?php while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{?>

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $row['lat'] . ','  . $row['lng']?>);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker
    (
        {
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map
        }
    );  

<?php }?>

}
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Investigate AJAX.

There are some articles in the Google docs which may help: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/articles

Have a look at *Using PHP/MySQL with Google Maps* and *Creating a store locator with PHP & MySQL*. The latter covers getting data out of a database and updating what's shown on the map (it's markers rather a polygon boundary, but the technique is very similar).

If you run into a specific coding difficulty, ask a question about that.